# Creating a Map-like structure using Array of ArrayLists

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, count, cpu-word

I need to create a Map like data structure using an Array or ArrayLists.

Quick program over view: My map holds objects of Word which is a string and holds a frequency count of how many times the word appears in a next file.

Here is code for MyMap, Program outputs nothing.

```
List<Word>[] table;
int tableSize;
int index;

public MyMap(int tableSize){
    table = new ArrayList[tableSize];
    this.tableSize = tableSize;
}

//Problem!!
public void put(Word w){
    index = Math.abs(w.hashCode()) % tableSize;
    if(table[index].isEmpty()){
        table[index].add(w);
    }
    else{ 
        w.increaseFreq();
        table[index].set(index, w);
    }

}

public void displayMap(){
    for(List<Word> w: table){
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

How about using either a Generic.Dictionary<string,Word> or a [KeyedCollection<string,Word>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms132438.aspx)?
If you use the KeyedCollection then you will need to inherit from it and provide a GetKeyForItem implementation.